# Markdown lists in Vim, automatically new bullet on CR

Tags: vim, markdown

Im using Markdown in Vim to write a lot of text. I'm wondering if its possible to make Vim automatically start the next line with a bullet * or - if I'm currently working on a text line in the list, and then presses enter ?

A lot of other text editors does this (e.g. Notational Velocity) so it would be great if this is possible in Vim as well.

What I want Vim to do:

```
- List element 1
- List element 2[press enter]
- (We are automatically here, with the bullet)
```

And I only want this for Markdown files.

Hope you understand! Thnx!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to set several vim variables to do it.

let's take '-' as example:

```
:set com=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://,b:#,:%,:XCOMM,n:>,b:-
```

here the last `'b:-'` is important. it means, vim will think '-' and a space([tab] too) as comment leader, and will automatically added after you pressed Enter or o (normal mode). this  set by `:set formatoptions` . see following lines.

you could check

```
:h comments
:h format-comments
```

for details

> :set formatoptions=tcroqln

here 'r' and 'o' are used for your requirement.

```
:h formatoptions 
:h fo-table
```

for details

EDIT

for adding markdown filetype. many resources on the net. simply gave a shot on google, got one:

http://technicalpickles.com/posts/using-markdown-in-vim/

change `au` to settings above, should work.

Comment: For better context, I believe Kent is suggesting you change the way Vim interprets comments, and then defining the syntax as if Markdown lists were inline comments.  @kent, you should add how to do file detection to run this in his vimrc automatically for my vote.

Comment: @Kent Thnx for the reply, but i does not seem to work when I try it. Nothing more happens after I run your command. I'm using MacVim, but I guess that should not be a problem.

Comment: @eivindml did you set paste option 'on' in your config? comment it out and try if you have it. it will disable formatoptions.

Comment: @Conrad.Dean yes, I am trying to do some trick with comment formatting. ft detection was added as a link :)

Comment: Now it works perfectly! I forgot to run this line ':set formatoptions=tcroqln'. Thank you. There is only one small thing, if its possible to indent the bullet when you press tab even when the cursor is after the bullet? But this is probably much harder.

Comment: vim has a 'ai' option. but it works not exactly what you described (cursor is after the bullet).  you may need to write your own function for it.

Comment: Try this for TextMate-style indenting: 

 imap <D-]> <C-t>
 imap <D-[> <C-d>