# Markdown lists in Vim

Tags: list, vim, markdown

When creating a list in a markdown file, I would like to insert a new item when pressing `<CR>`. I
want that to apply to both ordered and unordered lists. That implies that, in ordered lists, the
list item number will increment automatically. Also, if I press `<CR>` on a list item with no
content, I would like to remove the item and add a new line, essentially ending the list; This is
the current behaviour.

I managed to achieve some of the functionality that I want thanks to [this StackOverflow
question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065967/markdown-lists-in-vim-automatically-new-bullet-on-cr)
with this autocommand:

```
autocmd Filetype markdown setlocal com=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://,b:#,:%,:XCOMM,n:>,b:- | set formatoptions=tcroqln
```

But that autocommand doesn't work with ordered lists and doesn't end the list when `<CR>` is pressed
on a blank list item.

Is it possible to add those two features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle the ordered lists, you could treat them as comments like you do with the `-` sigil, just add `:setlocal com+=b:1.` This won't auto-increment, but I think Markdown does this for you when rendering the list, anyway.

There's no built-in logic for ending a list, but you can simply press `<C-U>` to remove the automatically inserted comment. If that's not good enough for you, an `:imap <buffer> <CR> <CR>...` mapping can detect such situations (by a function to be invoked in the `...` part) and then remove that automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That could be good enough, but isn't there a way to auto-increment the ordered lists? Maybe through a function instead of using Vim's comments feature?

Comment: I'm not aware of any built-in autoincrement; you could build that into the `<CR>` mapping I've hinted at. Why don't you just use `1.` for all list items; this makes shuffling around lines easier.

Comment: I'm a bit of a perfectionist. Having incrementing numbers is more readable. I've been trying to write a function to do it, but I barely know vimscript, so I am having a hard time doing it.. But I will accept your answer anyway, I'll try to do the extra work myself.

Answer (score 2):

Bullets.vim is a plugin that that makes this a lot easier than modifying the comments command.

https://github.com/dkarter/bullets.vim

You can insert a bulleted list by typing "-", and the following line will automatically insert a bullet.

You can also insert a numbered list by typing "1.", and subsequent lines will be automatically numbered in order.

From the readme:

> Bullets.vim is a Vim plugin for automated bullet lists.
>
> ## Usage
>
> In markdown or a text file start a bulleted list using - or *. Press
> return to go to the next line, a new list item will be created.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim`

```
" list markers (*, -, 1.)
function! s:list_marker() abort
  let line = substitute(getline(line('.')), '^\s*', '', '')
  let marker = matchstr(line, '^\([*-]\|\d\+\.\)\s')
  if !empty(marker) && marker == line
    return "\<c-u>"
  endif
  if marker =~ '\d'
    let marker = marker + 1 . '. '
  endif
  return "\<cr>" . marker
endfunction
inoremap <expr><buffer> <cr> <sid>list_marker() 
nmap <buffer> o A<cr>
```